# Android Issu with SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with database connection in my Android application. Strange thing is that everything was working fine. One fine morning, I started getting this problem. And with the existing well running applications as well.

I believe it is a kind of environment issue, but cant track it. Need your help guys. I have checked existing posts in SOF. Tried all suggested, nothing helping.

My DB connection program :

```
  package com.intw.jokes;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
  import android.util.Log;

  public class DatabaseUtil extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public SQLiteDatabase DB;
public String DBPath;
public static String DBName = "JOKES";
public static final int version = '1';
public static Context currentContext;;


public DatabaseUtil(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, version);
    currentContext = context;
    DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

}

public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseObject(){
    return this.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void closeDBConnection(SQLiteDatabase DB){
    if(null != DB)
        DB.close();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void createDatabase() {
    boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();
    //dbExists = false;
    if (dbExists) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);

        DB.close();
    }
}




private boolean checkDbExists() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

    }
    boolean test = checkDB != null ? true : false; 
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return test;
}
```

}

and my log :

```
    03-21 10:13:56.844: E/Trace(780): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    03-21 10:13:59.794: E/SQLiteLog(780): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
    03-21 10:13:59.794: E/SQLiteLog(780): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/data/data/com.intw.jokes/databases/JOKES) - 
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.intw.jokes/databases/JOKES'.
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at com.intw.jokes.DatabaseUtil.checkDbExists(DatabaseUtil.java:111)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at com.intw.jokes.DatabaseUtil.createDatabase(DatabaseUtil.java:49)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at com.intw.jokes.AllJokesActivity.configureDatabase(AllJokesActivity.java:201)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at com.intw.jokes.AllJokesActivity.onCreate(AllJokesActivity.java:80)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    03-21 10:13:59.834: E/SQLiteDatabase(780):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-21 10:14:00.534: D/dalvikvm(780): GC_CONCURRENT freed 304K, 9% free 7416K/8135K, paused 16ms+27ms, total 130ms
    03-21 10:14:00.534: D/dalvikvm(780): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
    03-21 10:14:01.894: D/gralloc_goldfish(780): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: Why are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper` without implementing `onCreate`/`onUpdate`?

Answer (score 1):

There is another way you can check database if exists. As answered by [Andre Rocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034511/android-database-sqlite-sqlitecantopendatabaseexception-unknown-error-code-14), Check the database like here inside `checkDbExists()` No need to be so complex as you are currently being now,

```
private boolean checkDbExists() {    
    File file= currentContext.getDatabasePath(DBName);
    return file.exists();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not getting the error any more. But my insert statements are not working.                                       this.DB = getWritableDatabase();
        if (count <= 0) {
            this.DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + champTableName + " Values ('" + statsDTO.getLevelNumber() + "','" + statsDTO.getTime() + "');");
        }
        this.DB.close();

Comment: The problem is that it was a working code. Not only this application, I have 50 add applications having the same issue. It could be something with environment. But not sure what

Comment: That is ok bro.. but, what about this one ? Is it solved or still some issue left

Comment: I am trying to reconfigure my Android. Let's see.