# On API23: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Tags: android, sqlite

Experts,

I have this error when run SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase, **on API 23** **only**, ob API 21 is ok.

According to previous question link below, the answer from **AB1209** pointed that should grant run time permission. However, this is API 23 new function.

I would like to use the app on both API 21 and 23. I have 2 question:

1. Isn't there a logic issue? I already grant permission in manifest, what is the good reason to do this on more time at run time? (My understanding is I need run time permission only when I did not grant in manifest during the install)
2. If I grant permission at run time, will it affect the usage when run on API 21? (I can still use the APP on API 21?)

Thanks.

Link:
[android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034511/android-database-sqlite-sqlitecantopendatabaseexception-unknown-error-code-14)

I already have below permission:

```
 android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: I'd suggest you research on the topic of runtime permissions, probably starting here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html. You obviously don't request them prior to 23, but you absolutely have to on > 23.

Comment: In my link, AB1209 has a link in his reply, I opened it and it begins: ...not only simplify permissions, but also to reduce the number of permissions needed... So I thought it is to simply things, now I understand it is to replace current. So I think my question solved. I just need to use both way, so it can be use for both API.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your activity:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And your code here:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}
```